# How to resolve the HCat Error - ClassNotFound - HCatOutputFormat not found

Tags: mapreduce, hive, hcatalog

How to resolve the error below, I have exported the Hcat-core.jar before running the code, kindly help

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatOutputFormat not found`

*Full Trace:*

```
2016-07-28 20:12:48,465 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Created MRAppMaster for application appattempt_1468985268798_44020_000002 
2016-07-28 20:12:48,653 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable 
2016-07-28 20:12:48,690 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Executing with tokens: 
2016-07-28 20:12:48,690 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Kind: YARN_AM_RM_TOKEN, Service: , Ident: (appAttemptId { application_id { id: 44020 cluster_timestamp: 1468985268798 } attemptId: 2 } keyId: 618886960) 
2016-07-28 20:12:48,811 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Using mapred newApiCommitter.     
2016-07-28 20:12:49,675 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: OutputCommitter set in config null 
2016-07-28 20:12:49,744 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService: Service org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster failed in state INITED; cause: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatOutputFormat not found 
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatOutputFormat not found   
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$1.call(MRAppMaster.java:478)  
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$1.call(MRAppMaster.java:458)  
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.callWithJobClassLoader(MRAppMaster.java:1560)     
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.createOutputCommitter(MRAppMaster.java:458)   
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.serviceInit(MRAppMaster.java:377)     
at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)      
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$4.run(MRAppMaster.java:1518)  
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)   
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)     
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.initAndStartAppMaster(MRAppMaster.java:1515)  
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.main(MRAppMaster.java:1448) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatOutputFormat not found  
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2195) 
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.JobContextImpl.getOutputFormatClass(JobContextImpl.java:222)    
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$1.call(MRAppMaster.java:474)  
... 11 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatOutputFormat not found    
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2101)        
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2193)   
... 13 more
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"exported the Hcat-core.jar"*??? Because that class is part of `hcat-core.jar`. So you have a CLASSPATH issue.

Comment: I mean I'm adding hcat-core jar in the class path .  Still I face this issue which is strange

Comment: Just to be sure: try `unzip -l hcat-core.jar | grep HCatOutputFormat` to check that the code you have forked refers to package `org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce` as expected...